SQLException timeout in Room KMP randomly
My code worked on an Android project without KMP. I'm migrating it to KMP and Compose MP and the app randomly crashes. I try changing the value of a Flow, which makes the other Flows emit new values from the Room database. Maybe the error is due to having many Flows emitting at the same instant. Every SELECT in the @DAO is collected through a Flow.
The versions of libraries:
agp = "8.5.0"
androidx-room = "2.7.0-alpha04"
ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.21"
sqlite = "2.5.0-alpha04"
kotlin = "2.0.0"
kotlinSerialization = "2.0.0"
koin = "3.6.0-Beta4"
koinComposeMultiplatform = "1.2.0-Beta4"

The Koin startKoin function instantiates Room like this:
actual fun platformModule(): Module = module {
    single<MyDatabase> { getDatabase(get()) }
}

fun getDatabase(
    context: Context
): MyDatabase {
    val dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbFileName)
    return Room.databaseBuilder<MyDatabase>(
        context = context,
        name = dbFile.absolutePath
    )
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration(true)
        .setDriver(BundledSQLiteDriver())
        .setQueryCoroutineContext(Dispatchers.IO)
        .build()
}

The error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.example, PID: 19964
android.database.SQLException: Error code: 5, message: Timed out attempting to acquire a connection
    at androidx.sqlite.SQLiteKt.throwSQLiteException(SQLite.kt:42)
    at androidx.room.coroutines.ConnectionPoolImpl.useConnection(ConnectionPoolImpl.kt:138)
    at androidx.room.coroutines.ConnectionPoolImpl$useConnection$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:16)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ScopeCoroutine.afterResume(Scopes.kt:28)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(AbstractCoroutine.kt:99)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:102)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:111)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:99)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:811)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:715)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:702)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@cd3755f, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@a461bac, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@f506075, AndroidUiDispatcher@21ae80a]


I've encountered the same issue as you on the Desktop build, although the Android and iOS builds work well.
After seeing your comment about "Every SELECT in the @DAO is collected through a Flow.", I inspected all the flows on my app. I was using combined flows from the DB.
Here is the suspected code in my app, that caused a crash on the Desktop build. I am also calling .setQueryCoroutineContext(Dispatchers.IO) on the Room database builder.
private val contentState = mediaRepository.observeMediaByPlaylistId(playlistId)
    .combine(playlistRepository.observePlaylistById(playlistId)) { mediaList, _ ->
        PlaylistDetailsStore.State.Content(mediaList)
    }
    .onStart { refreshMediaOnStart(playlistId) }
    .catch { throwable -> handleError(throwable) }

The issue was resolved for me after changing the context to Dispatchers.IO with the flowOn operator after combine.
private val contentState = mediaRepository.observeMediaByPlaylistId(playlistId)
    .combine(playlistRepository.observePlaylistById(playlistId)) { mediaList, _ ->
        PlaylistDetailsStore.State.Content(mediaList)
    }
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    .onStart { refreshMediaOnStart(playlistId) }
    .catch { throwable -> handleError(throwable) }

I think it may be related to the Room side, which doesn't correctly set query context for combined flows on the desktop side.
I hope it fixes your issue as well!

It seems to have improved the frequency at which the app crashes, but it still does.

I reported the bug in the IssueTracker of Room and the developers answered that they found it and made a fix for it.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/347737870

I am seeing this same issue using room 2.7.0-alpha05.
While the room library is fixed the workaround that I've found is to close the database when we receive the error
android.database.SQLException: Error code: 5, message: Timed out attempting to acquire a connection

After RoomDatabase.close() is called new queries work normally.
This is not a long term solution! But without that the database cannot be accessed because it is locked.

Thank you. Developers said they would fix it in next version, which should arrive soon.
